# Best way of returning a random boolean value

Tags: ruby

I've been using this for some time to return either `true` or `false` when building fake seed data. Just wondering if anybody has a better, more succinct or verbose way of returning either `true` or `false`.

```
rand(2) == 1 ? true : false
```

Comment: Per the answer by @a'r, did you realize that `rand(2)==1` is already a boolean value?

Answer (score 268, accepted):

A declarative snippet using [Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-sample):

```
random_boolean = [true, false].sample
```

Comment: Damn, I totally forgot I posted this question. Thanks so much for the bang-on answer!

Comment: **`[true, false].sample` is faster** than `rand(2) == 1`. When I performed each operation *10 million times* the `rand` method was 2.179s. The `sample` method was 1.645s.

Comment: [true, false].sample is not faster than rand > 0.5

Answer (score 37):

How about removing the ternary operator.

```
rand(2) == 1
```

Comment: It is more compact, but I do like `[true, false].sample` better because it is instantly obvious what it does. `rand(2) == 1` would work with ruby < 1.9 though, which is good.

Comment: Since there's only `0` and `1`, you could also use `rand(2).zero?`

Answer (score 22):

I like to use `rand`:

`rand < 0.5`

**Edit**: This answer used to read `rand > 0.5` but `rand < 0.5` is more technically correct. `rand` returns a result in the [half-open range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology) [0,1), so using `<` leads to equal odds of half-open ranges [0,0.5) and [0.5,1). Using `>` would lead to UNEQUAL odds of the closed range [0,0.5] and open range (.5,1).

Comment: This is perfect. The sample method produces (in theory) a **50%** probability but with this one you can adjust that probability. Say, I want a **70%** chance of getting a true value would be `rand > 0.3`

Comment: @JGonzalezD And to make it more straightforward and readable: `rand < 0.7` for **70%**

Answer (score 4):

I usually use something like this:

```
rand(2) > 0
```

You could also extend Integer to create a to_boolean method:

```
class Integer
  def to_boolean
    !self.zero?
  end
end
```

Comment: In ruby, only false and nil are falsey, I strongly recommand not to monkeypatch this kind of behavior.

Comment: better yet, `rand(2).zero?`